# Use email as username in Mediawiki

Tags: mediawiki, mediawiki-extensions

I encounter some issues while I want to integrate my mediawiki to my enterprise LDAP server with LDAPExtension. Our LDAP server uses email as uid, so I have to use email as the input username in mediawiki. But while I login with email, after LDAP  authentication pass, mediawiki always prompt: "Auto-creation of a local account failed: You have not specified a valid username." , it means the username is invalid.
I also tried to create a mediawiki user with email as username, it has same error.

So is it possible to let mediawiki ignore username validation to let email can be a username?

Answer (score 3):

Add these lines to the bottom of your `LocalSettings.php`:

```
$wgUserrightsInterwikiDelimiter = "%";
$wgInvalidUsernameCharacters = "%:";
```

- $wgUserrightsInterwikiDelimiter specifies what character to use in database for interwiki delimiters, by default it has value `@` and leads to error if you will try to create account with `@` in username
- $wgInvalidUsernameCharacters - list of characters restricted to be used in usernames, original value is `@:`

Answer (score 1):

Change [`$wgInvalidUsernameCharacters`](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:$wgInvalidUsernameCharacters).

---

Note that [logging in with the email address](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/Login_via_e-mail_address) might become possible at some point.

Comment: Is the login via-email feature available now or when will it available if not?

Comment: Whenever someone volunteers to work on it. The feature got [nearly finished](https://gerrit.wikimedia.org/r/#/c/229140/) about a year ago, but then changes to the authentication framework invalidated some parts of it, so it needs a significant update.